# Why aren’t there more stock market prediction tools available?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-analysis, forecasting

Investing in stocks depends on multiple factors. In order to estimate the approximate best time can be done with experience, various calculations, etc.

With the rise of Machine Learning, Deep Learning, etc. there are numerous prediction models where anyone could easily build their own solution to predict prices and the validation data is also quite accurate.

However, I don't see many such commercially available online tools that people could use to predict upcoming values regardless of the liability of the results given. Is there any reason for this ?

Comment: Thank you @PeteB.for your prompt comment. However ML is quite used in similar domains. Since you have a lot of more technical knowledge in the domain will it be possible for you to direct me to some references or provide with keywords to dig deeper on this topic  ?

Comment: "In order to estimate the approximate best time can be done with experience, various calculations, etc." No, it can't.

Comment: Obviously anyone who has such a tool is doing the opposite of whatever it predicts will happen, until it cancels out the entire prediction and there's nothing left to predict.

Comment: "With the rise of Machine Learning, Deep Learning, etc. there are numerous prediction models where anyone could easily build their own solution to predict prices and the validation data is also quite accurate." There really isn't any reason to believe this.  Deep algorithms and machine learning are good at predicting and building upon hard data - but stocks are driven by *human behavior*, something computers have always struggled to predict.

Comment: @Zibbobz Actually if there are patterns in human behaviour, machine learning should be able to find them just fine. The problem is what Allure said.

Comment: You might want to read about [inefficient markets](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/inefficientmarket.asp), which is what a prediction tool is trying to take advantage of. The problem is, inefficiencies are *eliminated* once enough people all start trying to take advantage of it.

Comment: @PeteB. Perhaps you research a company called "Renaissance Technologies", and how effectively they use predictive models to capitalize largely on short term market fluctuations to achieve  80% year over year returns.

Answer (score 102):

If one could build a model for accurately predicting future stock prices then:

1. Why would anyone share it?
2. Wouldn't there be some individuals  cornering the market, making people like Peter Lynch, Warren Buffet and a host of very successful hedge fund managers look like amateurs?

There are many commercially available tools such as you describe.  They are quite successful at taking the money of gullible people who think that simply buying some software is the road to riches.

Comment: Thank you @Bob for your comment. Really interesting points. Is there any major reason that you feel or believe why those commercially available tools are not working. I was searching check out, I felt those are not quite well built both prediction and UI/UX wise

Comment: I have nothing more than anecdotal evidence to offer you.  In nearly 4 decades of investing and trading, I have seen countless newsletters, stockbrokers, purveyors of technical analysis software, programmers, online individuals and web sites claim to have  the ability to consistently select winning stocks, options, futures and other predict other cosmic events.  Some occasionally have winning streaks but very, very few ever outperform.  But who knows?  It's a big haystack.  Maybe I missed the ONE guy who found the Holy Grail. :->)

Comment: @Bob Baerker: Yes, you can make mone with such a tool - by selling it to the gullible :-)  You also have to consider the Heisenberg effect of the widespread use of such a tool: if a large fraction of investors start using, that in itself changes the behavior of the market, meaning the tool no longer works.  (See "stock kiting".)

Comment: I think you are missing the point here. The tool doesn't have to outperform professional traders, it just has to outperform the amateurs to make it profitable for both sides. Similar to managed funds.

Comment: I downvoted because I think this answer is wrong - per Nelson's answer, these tools exist.

Comment: @Allure, Nelson's example supports this answer; not debunks it. The algo in question is proprietary, rather than commercial, hence the need to steal it.

Comment: @Aron but the algorithm exists - this answer makes it sound like it doesn't.

Comment: @Allure Bob's answer deny that such an algorithm would be available for public use, not that they exists.

Comment: @user3399 how are you and Aron getting that impression? The first sentence of Bob's answer starts with a conditional in unlikely to happen (at least that's how I read it).

Comment: @Allure You went down the wrong rabbit hole with your inductive logic. The first sentence merely implies that actors capable of bringing the "Commercial Product" into being, would act in a certain way. The second sentence implies that such an actor would not take the steps required to create the "Commercial Product" even though they were capable of doing so. The third piece of the puzzle, is implied, that actors incapable of creating the "Commercial Product" would not create the "Commercial Product". Therefore, no actors would create the "Commercial Product".

Comment: "Why would anyone share it?" The same reason why funds exist, because you earn more money if you not just manage your own savings but also get a share of somebody else's profit.

Comment: @user3399 They do exist and they are available for public use. Just search for "Robo-Advisor".

Comment: @Chris: They exist, but do they actually work as claimed?  That is, accurately forecast future stock prices.  Or is this just another example of making money by selling "advice" to the gullible?

Comment: @jamesqf Of course they work, why wouldn't they? It's actually very simple to outperform the average trader as even the S&P500 outperforms them. You won't get rich over night, you'll just get a little bit extra. I'm really wondering why the people here have higher expectations on an algorithm than on any other method of trading.

Comment: Question #1 has a very simple answer - because someone will pay you for it. It's the same reason every other commercially available software on the planet exists.

Comment: @Nuclear Wang - Yes, there's ton of commercial software available out there.  There's an entire industry built around technical analysis software.  Toss in some price  data and it will rank them and spit out the picks.  But you have to differentiate all of that from something that actually works.  If something works, it would be sold to the big players for big money because an edge will cease to work once the edge is widely known.  Have you ever heard of the trading desks at investment banks sharing their trading edges?

Comment: @BobBaerker I get it, but the self-defeating nature of widely available stock prediction methods is notably absent from the answer. For readers who aren't aware of that, the reasons to *not* share the method aren't obvious. As far as software goes, it's extremely unusual to have a valuable, useful program that becomes *less* valuable the wider its user base. It's a rather unintuitive in many ways.

Comment: @Chris: You're obviously using a different definition of "work" than I am.  A prediction tool that works, according to my definition, should do significantly better than just sticking your money in an index fund.

Comment: @jamesqf In addition to the Heisenberg effect, there is also the *Hindenberg* effect such as seen when algorithm trading causes flash crashes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_analysis_(finance) of relevance. There are a number of computer programs modelling and doing what OP is asking to the best of the current knowledge. They are, understandably, proprietary.

Comment: @jamesqf I'm not saying that it should do that, just using it as an example that it's possible.

Answer (score 59):

These tools exist (see [Nelson's answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/126986/why-aren-t-there-more-stock-market-prediction-tools-available/127001#127001)), but they aren't available for purchase because once they become publicly available, they cease to work. The logic goes something like this.

1. Suppose the stock of company A is currently trading at $100 each.
2. The software predicts that it will go up to $120. Therefore you buy.
3. Once you buy, you move the market. You can only buy if someone is willing to sell. In fact the price of $100 is because there's someone willing to sell the stock at $100/each, and someone is willing to buy at $100/each (this simplifies a little; usually there is an "ask" and "bid" price, where the asking price is the minimum price the seller is willing to sell for, and the bid price is the maximum price a buyer is willing to pay). Once you buy, there are fewer sellers who still own the stock + are willing to sell for $100/each. Eventually there are no more of them, and the stock price goes up.
4. Since the stock price has gone up, you make less profits. For example if you buy at $100 and sell at $120, you make 20% profits. If you buy at $101 and sell at $120, you make less than 20%.

If the software is always accurate, *and* the seller also has access to that software, then they are not going to want to sell for $100. They will only sell for $120. You will not be able to profit off it.

Another way of looking at it is that, by making the prediction known, you also make the prediction no longer useful. Your predictor is great as long as it doesn't influence the system, but if you sell the predictor, then the system reacts to the predictor's predictions, and you can't make money anymore (see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412321/why-do-the-laws-of-physics-fail-to-predict-the-behavior-of-frustrators) I asked on the Physics SE for another example).

Therefore, it does not make sense to sell them. If you invent one, you are better off keeping it to yourself and yourself only.

Comment: An alternative strategy to make money from predictions, which has the opposite effect of this post and also works very well: Publish a "tip sheet" (or start a Youtube channel) recommending "penny shares" with low liquidity. Buy your "predictions" before you publish them. When your hopeful customers buy, they push up the prices, and you sell. In the next edition, you show the price rise to prove how good your predictions are.

Comment: @alephzero that's also known as "pump and dump" and is illegal ...

Comment: The people who got rich during the Gold Rush were the ones who sold provisions and services to the prospectors, not so much the prospectors themselves. Unless you have lots of money to invest, you can probably make more money selling your software than trying to use it alone.

Comment: This explains why the tool would break if everyone in the market had access to the same predictions. But I see no reason why you couldn't charge an insane price tag for the method, which would only allow a few people to invest according to the predictions. You certainly can't sell the tool to everyone, but why can't you sell it to a handful of people? Selling it to one person could still net a profit of many millions, while not appreciably affecting the method's accuracy.

Comment: @NuclearWang trades are not secret. Unless you're dealing with a security with very high trading volume you aren't going to be able to buy/sell enough of it fast enough to keep the tail chasers off your six.

Comment: @JaredSmith But wouldn't that apply whether you share the method or not? This answer suggest such methods exist and do work because they are kept secret, but you seem to be suggesting there's no way to keep an investment strategy under wraps.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The system is fundamentally self-correcting.  There have in fact been many **successful** attempts in the past to develop algorithms which perform significantly better than average at predicting the market, but as soon as they become known to other traders, they stop working.

Comment: @NuclearWang they exist, and they exist at ginourmous hedge funds that are snarfing $0.01 per share 1 millisecond ahead of their peers, not spotting a 20% misprice. And no one else has the capital to do that. We pour more of our collective effort and intelligence into short term securities pricing than literally any other endeavor.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft : for anyone who tries to use those successful attempts to prove that such methods generally work, I only have one word to say: https://xkcd.com/1827/

Comment: @vsz: The market can be _modeled_ as random, but it's actually fairly predictable in specific ways. This is why pump-and-dump, insider trading, and many other schemes are so successful, and need to be enforced using laws instead. Dismissing _all_ successful attempts at finding other ways it's predictable as pure luck is disingenuous.

Comment: @jamesqf as I recall, the response to the American Problem is that if you have knowledge of a thing, and you use it in the market, that knowledge disseminates to others just by being used in the market, and this dissemination interferes with the ability to make money from the market.

Comment: @vsz: which brings us to the next problem for the potential buyer of the algorithm. How do they distinguish between the algorithm that (still) works when it is much cheaper & easier to develop a likely looking algorithms that works well in hindsight (overfitting) than an acutally well working one (says my professional machine learning experience in a very different field)...

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Human-made trading strategies (as opposed to ML-generated ones) are themselves overfit to various market cycles c.f. *Fooled By Randomness*, N. Taleb. If they can't tell the difference with humans, they sure won't be able to with models. One born every minute.

Comment: @JaredSmith: of course. The same is true also for "human predictive models" in other fields, see also various forms of apophenia. I'd actually go even a steop further: I suspect that our bias towards false positive recognition of patterns is one of the reasons behind ML overfitting: we're bad at recognizing overfit ML models and in consequence don't penalize enough.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX yes indeed. I wonder how many shouts of "eureka!" over the centuries have been driven by confirmation bias.

Comment: @Ross Presser: That was humor/sarcasm :-)  I agree about the effect of using knowledge in the market.  But really my point was that I was smart enough to make money by other means, and (after some early learning experiences) smart enough to just put money in index funds rather than trying to actively trade :-)

Answer (score 25):

They exist, but it's not for you to buy.

Here is a [story about Ke Xu, quantitative analyst](https://www.scmp.com/magazines/post-magazine/long-reads/article/2181637/chinese-maths-prodigy-turned-hedge-fund-coder-and).

Basically, the algorithms exist, but they are closely guarded secrets. Someone tried to steal them and got sued into the ground, along with travel bans, extradition, repeat jail time, private detectives tracking their parents in CHINA (Company was in UK). The legal team couldn't get the government to keep the "target" locked up, so the legal team started suing the government.

Very impressive article... a bit extreme, but if it is worth hundreds of millions of dollars, I would do the same thing.

Just to give you an idea of how much money these algorithms are worth, the analyst got £400,000 as a bonus. He got upset because he was expecting a million... and the algorithm earned his boss an undisclosed amount of millions of dollars.

Comment: The impressive thing is, the guy fled from London to Hong Kong, bound for Mainland China, and the legal team in UK acted so fast, the dude got stopped in Hong Kong and extradited back to the UK. This is a PRIVATE COMPANY that did this.

Comment: Interesting read. The firm acted with lightning speed or he would be back in China and there would be nothing that they could do.

Comment: Had he left on a Friday, not say anything till he was back in China and then resigned by email, he would not be caught.

Comment: @stackoverblown To be honest, I think he would've been assassinated or outright kidnapped. It's not like the guy had special protection, and with enough money anything can happen in China.

Comment: I am not sure the boss of G-Research wants to cross that line. Otherwise some goons would have already raided and ransacked Xu's mother's flat/apartment for the laptops, memory sticks etc. Or maybe they've already done. Do we even know?

Answer (score 4):

> However, I don't see many such commercially available online tools that people could use to predict upcoming values regardless of the liability of the results given. Is there any reason for this ?

Because every stock investor has a simple, free tool to predict upcoming values of stocks. It's called compound interest and the formula is:

```
P = P0 * k^t
```

Where `P` is the future price, `P0` is the initial price, `t` is the time and `k` is the compounded interest. Typical values is `k = 1.08`. To arrive at a more accurate value for `k`, one can look at dividend yield, inflation and GDP growth.

Why would I pay for a commercial tool, if I know this free tool is exactly as accurate as any offered commercial tool? That is, the tool is not very accurate in the short run, but let's say over a period of 50 years, it starts to have some value.

Comment: The OP believes that stock picking and market timing work. This answer doesn't really help the OP, because it doesn't offer any evidence for its assertion that they don't work. Nor is the assertion necessarily true, e.g., there's something called the weekend effect, which some economists argue is a real bias that just doesn't get efficiently arbitraged away for small stocks. What would be more accurate and helpful would be to explain that if there were some market anomaly that *was* easy to exploit, it would get arbitraged away.

Comment: 50 years? Most people don't want to wait that long.

Comment: A compound interest formula doesn't predict the price of stocks.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers points out: if this exists - it's not shared.  The more widely used they are, the less valuable they become.

Additionally, nobody really knows what's going to happen with any given stock - and if they did (and acted on that information) there are other problems.

Oh, and because people like Elon Musk can tweet that Tesla is over priced and have it drop by 20%.

There's **so** many variables, that if someone actually worked out a model that worked, why would they want to share it (instead of benefiting directly)*?  And even if they did share it - it's usefulness would diminish.

*Remember that wealth is relative.  If I make $1mil, and I show everyone else how to make the same amount, now we all have an extra $1mil - thereby removing my additional financial power from having more money.

Answer (score 2):

These tools simply don't exist. Many will try to sell you them, but in reality they don't work in real life. I worked in a hedge fund that spent years making these and the reality is that the vast majority of tools simply don't make money in real life. They don't take into account multiple risk factors, trading costs, legal issues, etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the stock market is a big chess tournament, and every time you win a chess match, you win money, and every time you lose a match, you lose money. Many humans are playing in the tournament, but some people are using software to play instead, and those with software are winning against those without. Once the software is shared, eventually everyone uses the same "winning" software, but as soon as that happens everyone just breaks even. As soon as one person gets better software, they start winning again until everyone else gets the new software too, and then everyone is just breaking even again. Unless someone keeps their special software secret, over time the end results collapse to a break even for everyone.

**Moral of this analogy:** Using AI for stock trading is widely in use today, and if it truly is "winning", then eventually the more people that use it, the less profitable it is compared to any set of random strategies. If you happen to have a secret winning tool or strategy, you probably won't want to share it. Therefore, if someone is trying to sell a winning tool or strategy, it probably isn't a winning tool or strategy
.

Answer (score 0):

**They are called Robo-Advisors and their market share is getting bigger every day.**

[What Is a Robo-Advisor?](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/roboadvisor-roboadviser.asp)

> Robo-advisors (also spelled robo-adviser or roboadvisor) are digital
> platforms that provide automated, algorithm-driven financial planning
> services with little to no human supervision.
>
> [...] The industry has experienced explosive growth as a result; client
> assets managed by robo-advisors hit $60 billion at year-end 2015 and
> are projected to reach US$2 trillion by 2020 and $7 trillion worldwide
> by 2025.

Writing a algorithm to outperform S&P500 is possible. There are a lot of quantitative analysis communities, which are sharing their results. Still **you need investors and lawyers** to build a successful enterprise. Therefore the entry into the financial market is a little bit more difficult than building yet another social start-up. As the industry is growing, we can expect to see more companies entering that market and making it more popular.

Comment: A robo-adviser is not a stock market prediction tool

Comment: @AakashM "Prediction" obviously doesn't exist as long as there is no time machine. We are talking about "projections" and also obviously Robo-Advisors have to estimate the potential growth to make a decision. OP's question wasn't specific enough if he wants to have the full details, e.g. target price, or if it's enough to select the stocks and a timeframe.

Comment: @AakashM How can a robo-adviser recommend one possible investment (or set of investments) over another without predicting what the results of taking the two options will be?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm pretty sure saying 'this equity market will typically return 8% pa over time' - or even a more complicated stochastic model - doesn't count as "a stock market prediction tool" _for the purposes of this question_. Now, _technically_ such a statement is of course "a prediction about the stock market", but looking at the question body rather than just the title, we see the asker is looking for something that can "predict prices". Roboadvisers don't do that.

Comment: @AakashM They do that to the extent it is possible for a widely-used tool to do it. The risk/reward trade-off is fundamental.